# Initializing a mock object internals before injecting it with @InjectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

I have something like

```
private static final CustomObject ObjectA = new CustomObject();

    @Mock
    Foo1 foo1;

    @Mock
    Foo2 Foo2 = new Foo2(ObjectA);

    @Mock
    Foo3 foo3;

    @InjectMocks
    ContainerClass container;
```

I want to initialize Foo2 with ObjectA before it gets injected in container. The above code is not working.

EDIT: I am trying to mock Foo2 but there is an internal object of Foo2 which i want to initialize with a real object, so when i call methods of Foo2, this internal object is utilized to give me results i need based on the values i provided during its construction.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: If you are mocking Foo2 then when you call methods of Foo2 the results cannot be defined by  how it was constructed. You need to define the results using Mockito.when

Answer (score 2):

> The above code is not working.

1) `@InjectMocks` uses much "magic" and is not necessary the clearest and debugable way to setup the mocks of the object under test.
Under the hoods, it tries multiple things : constructor injection, property setter injection, field injection.
But if it fails to inject, that will not report failure :

> If any of the following strategy fail, then Mockito won't report
>   failure; i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself.

As alternative you could so explicitly set the dependencies of the object under test.

2) Side but important note : name your variables with a lowercase as first letter. Naming them with the class name is not readable and conventional.

3) This doesn't make sense :

```
@Mock
Foo2 Foo2 = new Foo2(ObjectA);
```

You instantiate `Foo2` that is then replaced by a Mockito mock.
Mocking `Foo2` behavior but letting its `ObjectA` dependency be a no mock object is not really logic.
By doing that, you don't mock really the dependencies of the object under test as your calling pattern is :

> object under test -> mock dep1 -> real object dep2

In this case, writing an integration test (without mocks) makes more sense.

As you unit test `ContainerClass`, you will test only the `ContainerClass` behavior.
The `ObjectA` method which you would like to get the result should be a call of `Foo2` to `ObjectA` which you mock the call to `Foo2` in your test.
Note that you don't need to mock `ObjectA` if you mock the method of its caller.

Here is a example :

```
public class Foo2{

    private ObjectA objectA;

    public Foo2(ObjectA objectA){
       this.objectA = objectA;
    }

    public Bar callObjectA(){
         return objectA.foo();
    }
}
```

What you need to mock here is `callToObjectA()`.

```
@Mock
Foo1 foo1;

@Mock
Foo2 foo2;

@Test
public void myMethod(){
   ContainerClass container = new ContainerClass(foo1, foo2);
   Bar mockedBar = new Bar(....);
   Mockito.when(foo2.callObjectA()).thenReturn(mockedBar);
   // invoke the method under test
   container.myMethod();
   // assertions ...
}
```

Comment: So is it possible to first mock ObjectA, then inject that in Foo2, and then finally inject everything in ContainerClass?

Comment: You could do even simpler. You don't need to mock `ObjectA` if you mock the method of its caller : `Foo2`

Comment: Method of the caller? Actually when i called that particular method which access ObjectA i was getting a null exception, so it seemed to me just doing a @Mock Foo2 foo2; was not initializing the internals of Foo2, and when that internal object was accessed by container object i was getting null exception.

Comment: Foo2 mock is probably not injected in the ContainerClass object. Really avoid `@InjectMocks`. I updated with a example for how to do by setting explicitly the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Code style notwithstanding, the problem you have is that `Foo2` isn't really a mock, because you're explicitly instantiating it. If you really want to use a "real" `Foo2` instance that is instantiated with the `Object2` instance, then consider using a `@Spy` annotation on `Foo2`. Then, the [`@InjectMocks`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation should do what you are expecting.